# How can I add logo as a brand (or with brand name) in Plotly-Dash (dbc.NavbarSimple)?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In the following code I want to add image(logo) as a brand or with the brand name.

```
def navbar():
navigation_bar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Tab 2", href='/tab2')),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Tab 3", href="/tab3")),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Tab 4", href="/tab4")),

    ],
    brand="Home",
    brand_href="/",
    sticky="top",
    color="light",
    dark=False,
    expand='lg', )

return navigation_bar
```

I want to add logo with the brand name something like this:
[image]

Comment: The documentation clearly shows how you could do it https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like:

```
navbar = dbc.Navbar(
[
    html.A(
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(html.Img(src = logo.png, height= "50px")),
                dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand(
                    html.H1("Title", className = "ml-2"))),
            ]
        )
    ),
    dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler", n_clicks=0),
    dbc.Collapse(
        search_bar, id="navbar-collapse", navbar=True, is_open=False
    ),
    dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler2"),
    dbc.Collapse(
        dbc.Nav(
            # right align dropdown menu with ml-auto className
            [dropdown], className="ml-auto", navbar=True
        ),
        id="navbar-collapse2",
        navbar=True,
        ),

],
```

and then pass it in `app.layout`

Make sure to import:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
```